# Why are these the outputs of my nested for loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, output, nested-loops

The code is shown below:

```
a = [1, 8, -1, -9];
b = [-5, 8, 1, -6, 7, 9];
for i=1:numel(a)
    c(i) = 0;
    for k = i : numel(a)
        c(i) = c(i) + a(k) + b(k);
    end
end

fprintf('%7.2f\n', c)
```

These are the corresponding outputs, please explain why:

```
  -3.00      (2 blank spaces in front)  
   1.00      (3 blank spaces in front)
 -15.00      (1 blank space  in front)
 -15.00      (1 blank space  in front)
```

Comment: is it your homework to explain the output? What output do you expect from the code?

Comment: Type `doc fprintf` on the MATLAB command prompt. Or look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) for a tutorial on `fprintf` format specifiers.

Comment: It's my homework to obtain those outputs, I just don't know how. I'm getting different numbers. @JimHawkins

Comment: Well if you run the code provided it gives exactly those outputs. It's a pretty easy algorithm, you can even do the calculations by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The "7" in format string '%7.2f\n' specifies a minimum width of... 7. The default behavior is right-justified (and has not be altered in the format string), so the minimum width of 7 characters is achieved by padding with spaces on the left. Such format strings are common to achieve aligned entries in a column of numbers when using a fixed-width font.

Is it a de facto user-interface standard that vertically stacked numbers should align at the decimal-point (also to a virtual decimal-point: aligning where the point would be even if not displaying the point). It's easier for a human to skim thru the list and understand relative magnitudes of the entries.